# Predecessor didn't know VCS

Tags: bash, git, version-control, versioning

So, I have a long list of folders that I need to import into a VCS (probably `git`). Has anyone any suggestions how to automate this process?

```sh
2016_09_02_Backup     2017_04_24_Backup         2018_10_23_001_WarExport
2016_09_08_Backup     2017_04_24_WarExport      2018_10_23_002_WarExport
2016_09_09_Backup     2017_06_26_Backup         2018_10_23_003_WarExport
2016_09_09_WarExport  2017_06_26_WarExport      2018_10_23_004_WarExport
2016_09_12_WarExport  2017_06_30_Backup         2018_10_23_005_WarExport
2016_09_13_WarExport  2017_06_30_WarExport      2018_10_23_006_WarExport
2016_09_14_WarExport  2017_07_11_Backup         2018_10_23_007_WarExport
2016_09_15_WarExport  2017_07_12_Backup         2018_10_23_008_WarExport
2016_09_16_WarExport  2017_07_13_Backup         2018_10_23_009_WarExport
2016_09_19_WarExport  2017_08_21_Backup         2018_10_24_001_WarExport
2016_09_20_WarExport  2017_08_21_WarExport      2018_10_24_002_WarExport
2016_09_22_Backup     2017_10_05_Backup         2018_10_24_003_WarExport
2016_09_22_WarExport  2017_10_05_WarExport      2018_11_22_001_WarExport
2016_09_26_Backup     2018_08_13_WarExport      2018_11_22_002_WarExport
2016_09_27_Backup     2018_08_14_WarExport      2018_11_29_Backup
2016_09_27_WarExport  2018_08_15_001_WarExport  2018_11_29_WarExport
2016_11_10_Backup     2018_08_15_002_WarExport  2018_12_12_Backup
2016_11_10_WarExport  2018_08_15_003_WarExport  2018_12_12_WarExport
2016_12_22_Backup     2018_08_15_004_WarExport  2019_04_10_WarExport
2016_12_23_Backup     2018_08_15_005_WarExport  2019_05_07_WarExport
2017_01_02_Backup     2018_08_15_006_WarExport  2019_05_27_WarExport
2017_01_31_Backup     2018_08_15_007_WarExport  2019_06_14_WarExport
2017_02_23_Backup     2018_08_15_Backup         2019_07_15_WarExport
2017_02_23_WarExport  2018_09_26_001_WarExport  2019_08_09_001_WarExport
2017_02_27_Backup     2018_09_26_002_WarExport  2019_08_09_002_WarExport
2017_02_27_WarExport  2018_10_11_WarExport      2019_08_09_003_WarExport
2017_03_13_Backup     2018_10_16_WarExport      2019_08_12_002_WarExport
2017_03_13_WarExport  2018_10_18_Backup         2019_08_12_003_WarExport
2017_03_30_Backup     2018_10_19_001_WarExport  2019_08_12_WarExport
2017_03_30_WarExport  2018_10_19_002_WarExport  2019_08_14_WarExport
2017_04_03_Backup     2018_10_19_003_WarExport  2020_04_28_Current
2017_04_03_WarExport  2018_10_22_WarExport
```

Every folder has about the same structure (code files, project settings etc) just evolving over time.

Comment: I guess, you need to export `*_Backup` ?

Comment: Hard to give any specific advice without knowing how similar the content of these directories is. The generic advice is: run a loop over these directories, split the name, format date, and commit the content of every directory in a separate commit faking date setting `$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE`.